# syntax error at or near " " postgresql function

Tags: postgresql

I have an function in postgresql. I don't know whether I made it a bit complicated. I have a select query and I need to append some more expressions into that. I am passing those expressions as input parameters.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_alldocuments(currUser text,
queryExp text,
query0 text,
query1 text)
RETURNS TABLE(fileleafref text,contenttypename text,fsobjtype text,id integer,conttypeid integer,contenttypeid integer,docicon text,encodedabsurl text,refId integer,filesizedisplay integer,created date,
createdby text,version text) AS $$

BEGIN
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'select distinct c.fileleafref, ct.contenttypename,c.fsobjtype,c.id,c.conttypeid,d.contenttypeid,c.docicon,c.encodedabsurl,d.ref_id as RefId,c.filesizedisplay,d.created,
                        d.createdby,c.version from public.documents d inner join public.documentcontent c on d.id=c.documentid inner join conttype ct on ct.id = c.conttypeid
                        where '
                         || quote_literal(queryExp) 
                         || ' versionflag=true and c.permissiontype ="1" or  (c.permissiontype="3" and c.createdby =currUser)  order by d.created desc limit 300)
                        union
                        (select distinct c.fileleafref, ct.contenttypename,c.fsobjtype,c.id,c.conttypeid,d.contenttypeid,c.docicon,c.encodedabsurl,d.ref_id as RefId,c.filesizedisplay,d.created,
                        d.createdby,c.version from public.documents d inner join public.documentcontent c on d.id=c.documentid inner join conttype ct on ct.id = c.conttypeid '
                        || quote_ident(query0) || 
                        ' where' || quote_ident(queryExp) || 'versionflag=true '|| quote_ident(query1) ||
                        ' order by d.created desc limit 300)';
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

in the function I am trying to append different expressions at different places of my select query.

The input variables are

```
currUser -  user1
queryExp  - metadata @> ''{"Year":"2011"}'' and metadata @> ''{"Country":"US"}'' and 

query0  - ,jsonb_array_elements(c.securitygppermission) as e(users) ,jsonb_array_elements_text(c.userspermission) as p(perm) 


 query1 - and (c.permissiontype='2' and e.users ->>'Deny'='false' and e.users ->>'Allow'='true' and e.users ->>'GroupName'='Manager'  and p.perm ='user1')
```

The complete select query sample is

```
select * from get_alldocuments('user1','metadata @> ''{"Year":"2011"}'' and metadata @> ''{"Country":"US"}'' and ',',jsonb_array_elements(c.securitygppermission) as e(users) ,jsonb_array_elements_text(c.userspermission) as p(perm)','and (c.permissiontype="2" and e.users ->>"Deny"="false" and e.users ->>"Allow"="true" and e.users ->>"GroupName"="Manager"  and p.perm ="user1")')
```

While executing the function its showing an error like

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "versionflag"
LINE 3: ...11"}'' and metadata @> ''{"Country":"US"}'' and ' versionfla...
                                                         ^
QUERY:  select distinct c.fileleafref, ct.contenttypename,c.fsobjtype,c.id,c.conttypeid,d.contenttypeid,c.docicon,c.encodedabsurl,d.ref_id as RefId,c.filesizedisplay,d.created,
                        d.createdby,c.version from public.documents d inner join public.documentcontent c on d.id=c.documentid inner join conttype ct on ct.id = c.conttypeid
                        where 'metadata @> ''{"Year":"2011"}'' and metadata @> ''{"Country":"US"}'' and ' versionflag=true and c.permissiontype ="1" or  (c.permissiontype="3" and c.createdby =currUser)  order by d.created desc limit 300)
                        union
                        (select distinct c.fileleafref, ct.contenttypename,c.fsobjtype,c.id,c.conttypeid,d.contenttypeid,c.docicon,c.encodedabsurl,d.ref_id as RefId,c.filesizedisplay,d.created,
                        d.createdby,c.version from public.documents d inner join public.documentcontent c on d.id=c.documentid inner join conttype ct on ct.id = c.conttypeid ",jsonb_array_elements(c.securitygppermission) as e(users) ,jsonb_array_elements_text(c.userspermission) as p(perm)" where"metadata @> '{""Year"":""2011""}' and metadata @> '{""Country"":""US""}' and "versionflag=true "and (c.permissiontype=2 and e.users ->>""Deny""=""false"" and e.users ->>""Allow""=""true"" and e.users ->>""GroupName""=""Manager""  and p.perm =""user1"")" order by d.created desc limit 300)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function get_alldocuments(text,text,text,text) line 4 at RETURN QUERY
********** Error **********
```

What is the issue? Am I concatenated in the correct way?

Comment: `FORMAT` is always a preference over such concatting. anyway I assume if you use `queryExp  - metadata @> '{"Year":"2011"}' and metadata @> '{"Country":"US"}' and ` it might work

Comment: @VaoTsun  removing that single quotes will not work as it works as an escape character. My select query is updated in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the issue. 'quote_indent' created the issue. The final function is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_alldocuments(
curruser text,
queryexp text,
query0 text,
query1 text)
RETURNS TABLE(fileleafref character varying, contenttypename character varying, fsobjtype character varying, id integer, conttypeid integer, contenttypeid character varying, docicon character varying, encodedabsurl character varying, refid character varying, filesizedisplay integer, created date, createdby character varying, version character varying) 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE 
ROWS 1000
AS $BODY$

BEGIN
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE '(select distinct c.fileleafref, ct.contenttypename,c.fsobjtype,c.id,c.conttypeid,cast(d.contenttypeid as varchar) as contenttypeid,c.docicon,c.encodedabsurl,d.ref_id as RefId,c.filesizedisplay,cast(d.created as date) created,
                        d.createdby,c.version from public.documents d inner join public.documentcontent c on d.id=c.documentid inner join conttype ct on ct.id = c.conttypeid
                        where '
                         || queryExp
                         ||  ' versionflag=true and c.permissiontype=''1'' or  (c.permissiontype=''3'' and c.createdby =''||  curruser ||'')  order by created desc limit 300)
                        union
                        (select distinct c.fileleafref, ct.contenttypename,c.fsobjtype,c.id,c.conttypeid,cast(d.contenttypeid as varchar) as contenttypeid,c.docicon,c.encodedabsurl,d.ref_id as RefId,c.filesizedisplay,cast(d.created as date) created,
                        d.createdby,c.version from public.documents d inner join public.documentcontent c on d.id=c.documentid inner join conttype ct on ct.id = c.conttypeid '
                        || query0 || 
                         ' where ' || queryExp || ' versionflag=true ' || query1 ||
                         'order by created desc limit 300);';
END

$BODY$;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I parse your query correctly then this parts looks wrong:

```
where 'metadata @> ''{"Year":"2011"}'' and metadata @> ''{"Country":"US"}'' and ' versionflag=true
```

Between the `where` and `versionflag=true` you have a string literal (single quoted string). So to postgresql it basically looks like you wrote `where 'string' versionflag=true` which doesn't make any sense. Looks like a comparison and a logical operator are missing.